# MongoDB return the lates record for each field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Suppose, I have this `rooms` collection:

```
{
    room: 'room1',
    owner: 'user1',
    time: 'time1'
},

{
    room: 'room1',
    owner: 'user1',
    time: 'time2'
},

{
    room: 'room2',
    owner: 'user1',
    time: 'time3'
},

{
    room: 'room2',
    owner: 'user1',
    time: 'time4'
},

{
    room: 'room3',
    owner: 'user1',
    time: 'time5'
},

{
    room: 'room3',
    owner: 'user1',
    time: 'time6'
}
```

In application I have array of rooms: `[room1, room2, room3]`

How can I retrieve for each room in rooms array the latest record by time? For example query should return this:

```
{
    room: 'room1',
    owner: 'user1',
    time: 'time2'
},

{
    room: 'room2',
    owner: 'user1',
    time: 'time4'
},

{
    room: 'room3',
    owner: 'user1',
    time: 'time6'
}
```

Comment: is `time` data type `string` ?

Comment: time is timestamp (milliseconds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mongoDB [aggregation pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/).

1> First match your criteria.

2> Sort by `time`.

3> Group by `room`.

4> Project fields

check below aggregation query :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
  "$match": {
    "room": {
      "$in": ["room1", "room2", "room3"] //macth criteria
    }
  }
}, {
  "$sort": {
    "time": -1 //sort by time 
  }
}, {
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$room", // group by room 
    "room": {
      "$first": "$room" // used mongo $first method
    },
    "owner": {
      "$first": "$owner"
    },
    "time": {
      "$first": "$time"
    }
  }
}, {
  "$project": { //project all fileds
    "_id": 0,
    "room": "$room",
    "owner": "$owner",
    "time": "$time"
  }
})
```

If your collection documents size more then `$sort` takes time to sort and groups, so instead of `$sort` use [$max](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) as below :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
  "$match": {
    "room": {
      "$in": ["room1", "room2", "room3"]
    }
  }
}, {
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$room",
    "time": {
      "$max": "$time" // use $max
    },
    "room": {
      "$first": "$room"
    },
    "owner": {
      "$first": "$owner"
    }
  }
}, {
  "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "room": "$room",
    "owner": "$owner",
    "time": "$time"
  }
})
```